# Automation Imacros.iim could not be opened in firefox

Tags: firefox, imacros, bookmarks

I have created an imacros file mine.imm in firefox and added as a bookmark (instruction: http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Firefox).

But when I try to open it, firefox show: "The address wasn't understood. Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because one of the following protocols (imacros) isn't associated with any program or is not allowed in this context"

I tried to follow this instruction (http://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&p=70238) but it does not work.

My version:

OS: Raspbian 9

Firefox: 52.3.0 (32b)

Imacros: 9.0.3

Please help, thank you.

Comment: I use firefox 52.3.0 esr (x64) with iMacros 8.9.7 under windows 7 professional, and the described instruction works well for me, hope this helps.

Comment: @Valera Hi, How could it be possible. Since iMacros 8.9.7 is only suitable for firefox version from 30 to 49 [link](https://addons.mozilla.org/nn-no/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/versions/)

Comment: Hi, as far as I can remember, I've copied it manually from an older portable version folder.